# Crashlytics crashing TestFlight app, without any crash log found

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-fabric

I found that calling to latest Fabric Crashlytics 3.7.0

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

causes my app to close / crash, but only when the app was distributed with TestFlight... it doesn't happen, even when build with release

It is the first thing called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, as i found out it is crashing the app, i moved it to another part of code, when a button is pressed and it crashed / closed the app

**The problem is, i cannot find any trace of a crashlog nowhere**, not in Settings -> Privacy... not when attaching to XCode and looking at the console

Comment: Apple should provide to you some crashlog but they have some delay :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a separate target for the AppStore distribution and looks like i forgot the Fabrics entry in the plist